# New WooCommerce option under Inventory > Sold individually section

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to add a new setting under Inventory > Sold individually setting. In fact I did that utilizing the `woocommerce_product_options_sold_individually` hook. The code I used is this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_sold_individually', 'custom_product_step_quantity', 99 );
function custom_product_step_quantity() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'                => 'product_step_quantity',
        'value'             => ! empty( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_step_quantity', true ) ) ? (int) get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_step_quantity', true ) : '',
        'label'             => 'Minimum step quantity',
        'desc_tip'          => true,
        'wrapper_class'     => 'custom-step-quantity',
        'description'       => 'The minimum step quantity - multiplier - of the items that can be added to the cart',
        'type'              => 'number',
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'step' => 1,
            'min'  => 1,
        ),
    ) );
}
```

The problem is that no matter what I've tried regarding CSS, I wasn't able to force it go to a new line. It only appears on the right of the Sold individually stock setting. I'm not a CSS specialist, so I can't figure this out. Can someone help me with this?

I just set up a sandbox WC site as a minimal reproducible example. The login info is:

```
URL: https://kind-kinkajou-kmqkl.instawp.xyz
Username: mobebabufa7100
Password: B2k1HGlPTbONEFJZy8QM
```

and according to the site, it'll be on for 8 hours.

The test product I created is https://kind-kinkajou-kmqkl.instawp.xyz/wp-admin/post.php?post=13&action=edit

Just go to the Inventory tab, and you will see that the new field is in the same line as the stock field.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately as it's the admin side of a live wc eshop, there will be many URLs, session IDs, etc in the source code. If you're familiar with WC, and have a Snippets plugin, you can copy/paste the above code in a new snippet, and you will see the problem in action.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I respect your solutions, and even by looking at your name 99% in the answers of a problem I know beforehand that their problem will be resolved. But this has to do with data organization, requirements etc. They asked me to implement it like this, and this is enough for me. I don't make questions, I don't judge their requirements... This turns to be a CSS nightmare, but still, there must be a solution with enough experimenting!

Answer (score 2):

Update To add a field below "Sold individually" option, use the following:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_sold_individually', 'custom_product_step_quantity', 99 );
function custom_product_step_quantity() {
    echo '</div><div class="show_if_simple show_if_variable">';';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'                => 'product_step_quantity',
        'value'             => ! empty( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_step_quantity', true ) ) ? (int) get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_step_quantity', true ) : '',
        'label'             => 'Minimum step quantity',
        'desc_tip'          => true,
        'wrapper_class'     => 'custom-step-quantity',
        'description'       => 'The minimum step quantity - multiplier - of the items that can be added to the cart',
        'type'              => 'number',
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'step' => 1,
            'min'  => 1,
        ),
    ) );
}
```

And the CSS rule:

```php
add_action( 'admin_head', 'custom_product_step_quantity_css', 99 );
function custom_product_step_quantity_css() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if ( in_array($pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php']) && $typenow === 'product' ) : ?>
    <style>.inventory_sold_individually {border-bottom-width:0px !important;}</style><?php
    endif;
}
```

Or use this CSS code line

```css
.inventory_sold_individually {border-bottom-width:0px !important;}
```

You will get *(with no separation line)*:

[image]

Comment: I bet it works, your name guarantees a working solution in regards to WC every time. However, I don't want it to be with a separator line; I want them to be in the same group!